# Integral formulation for the solution of $xy'' + y' = y$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say that $y$ satisfies the following ODE:
$$xy'' + y' = y$$

I want to formulate $y$ as a contour integral.

I know that the final result I should get is:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C}{\frac{1}{t}e^{\sqrt{x}(t+1/t)}dt}$$
where $C$ is an appropriate contour.

However, I don't know where to start in order to derive this result.

PS: There are some similarities between this integral formulation and that of the [Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), $I_n(x)$, as we can observe by looking at expression (1) in Mathworld.

Comment: [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) is probably the place the start.

Comment: Substitute your final result into the equation and check that it is satisfied

Comment: @DavidH, I also suspect that's the place to start, but I don't know how to use it, because $y(x)$ supposedly is a real function.
$\\$
Vladimir, I'm interested in finding a constructing approach to derive the result.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large xy'' + y' = \left(xy'\right)'}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, I did notice I can write the ODE in the self-adjoint form $(xy')^{'}-y=0$, but I don't see in which way I can use it to make any progress.

Comment: @MayaLda. Yes. It's true. I was thinking in an integral equation for ${\rm y}\left(x\right)$. It was just an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{x = -\,{1 \over 4}\,t^{2}\quad\imp\quad t = 2\ic x^{1/2}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \totald{}{x}&=\totald{t}{x}\,\totald{}{t}=\ic x^{-1/2}\,\totald{}{t}
> =-\,{2 \over t}\,\totald{}{t}
> \\[3mm]\totald[2]{}{x}&=\underbrace{-\,{2 \over t}}_{\ds{\totald{t}{x}}}\
> \totald{}{t}\bracks{-\,{2 \over t}\,\totald{}{t}}
> ={4 \over t^{2}}\,\totald[2]{}{t} - {4 \over t^{3}}\,\totald{}{t}
> \end{align}

Set $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{t} \equiv {\rm y}\pars{-\,{1 \over 4}\,t^{2}}}$:
$$
-\,{1 \over 4}\,t^{2}\bracks{%
{4 \over t^{2}}\,
\totald[2]{{\rm u}\pars{t}}{t} - {4 \over t^{3}}\,\totald{{\rm u}\pars{t}}{t}}
- {2 \over t}\,\totald{{\rm u}\pars{t}}{t} = {\rm u}\pars{t}
$$

> and
>   $$
> t^{2}\,\totald[2]{{\rm u}\pars{t}}{t} + t\,\totald{{\rm u}\pars{t}}{t} +
> \pars{t^{2} - 0^{2}}{\rm u}\pars{t} = 0
> $$
>   which is a [Bessel Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).
>   Solutions are given for linear combinations of $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{2\ic\root{x}}}$
>   where $\ds{{\rm u}}$'s are Bessel functions.

$\color{#c00000}{\ds{\mbox{The integral representation should arise from the Bessel functions integral representations.}}}$

Comment: this sounds like a nice way to arrive at the integral formulation. however, I was not expecting to have to resort to Bessel functions' properties. I just casually stumbled upon the similar integral formulation, while working in a non-related problem. For this reason, I will leave the question open for the next couple of days, in hope of a more constructive approach, before I accept your answer. thanks, Felix!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds$ ,

Then $x(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)''+(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)'-\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$x\int_Cs^2e^{xs}K(s)~ds+\int_Cse^{xs}K(s)~ds-\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_Cs^2e^{xs}K(s)~d(xs)+\int_C(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_Cs^2K(s)~d(e^{xs})+\int_C(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s^2e^{xs}K(s)]_C-\int_Ce^{xs}~d(s^2K(s))+\int_C(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s^2e^{xs}K(s)]_C-\int_Ce^{xs}(s^2K'(s)+2sK(s))~ds+\int_C(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s^2e^{xs}K(s)]_C-\int_Ce^{xs}(s^2K'(s)+(s+1)K(s))~ds=0$

$\therefore s^2K'(s)+(s+1)K(s)=0$

$s^2K'(s)=-(s+1)K(s)$

$\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}=-\dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac{1}{s^2}$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=-\int\left(\dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{1}{s^2}\right)ds$

$\ln K(s)=-\ln s+\dfrac{1}{s}+c_1$

$K(s)=\dfrac{ce^\frac{1}{s}}{s}$

$\therefore y=\int_C\dfrac{ce^{xs+\frac{1}{s}}}{s}~ds$

But since the above procedure in fact suitable for any complex number $s$ ,

$\therefore y_n=\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{c_ne^{xk_nt+\frac{1}{k_nt}}}{k_nt}d(k_nt)=c_n\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{e^{k_nxt+\frac{1}{k_nt}}}{t}dt$

For some $x$-independent real number choices of $a_n$ and $b_n$ and $x$-independent complex number choices of $k_n$ such that:

$\lim\limits_{t\to a_n}te^{k_nxt+\frac{1}{k_nt}}=\lim\limits_{t\to b_n}te^{k_nxt+\frac{1}{k_nt}}$

$\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dfrac{e^{k_nxt+\frac{1}{k_nt}}}{t}dt$ converges

For $n=1$ , the best choice is $a_1=0$ , $b_1=\infty$ , $k_1=-1$ when $\text{Re}(x)\geq0$

$\therefore y_1=C_1\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-xt-\frac{1}{t}}}{t}dt$ when $\text{Re}(x)\geq0$

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but I don't see how I get to:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C}{\frac{1}{t}e^{\sqrt{x}(t+1/t)}dt}$$
from your conclusion.

Comment: @Maya Lda.: you can then change $t$ to $\dfrac{t}{\sqrt x}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Assume: $$y(x) = \int_C \! e^{xt}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

This means that:

$$y'(x) = \int_C \! te^{xt}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,\,\, \text{and} \,\,y''(x) = \int_C \! t^2e^{xt}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Substitute this into our equation to find:

$$\int_C  (xt^2+t-1)e^{xt}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = 0$$

We are going to find another function $g(t)$ such that it has the following properties:

$$g(t) = t^2f(t) \,\,\, \text{and} \, \,\, g'(t) = (t-1)f(t)$$

With clever manipulations (aka division) we say that $$\log(g) = \int\!\dfrac{g'(t)}{g(t)}\mathrm{d}t = \int\! \dfrac{t-1}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t = \log(t) + \dfrac{1}{t}$$

$$g(t) = te^{1/t}$$

$$f(t) = \dfrac{1}{t}e^{1/t}$$

Now we can say that our solution is

$$y(x) = \int_C \! \frac{1}{t}e^{xt+1/t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

$g(t)$ was chosen in such a way that $e^{xt}(xg(t) + g'(t)) = (xt^2+t-1)e^{xt}f(t) = (e^{xt}t^2f(t))'$.

This is the technique I learned to solve equations of your type. I would imagine that assuming a form like $y(x) = \int_c \!e^{\sqrt{x}t}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ would result in a solution similar to the one you have provided. Naturally, the factor of $1/(2\pi i)$ may be added at the end.

Comment: your approach doesn't seem to help because, when you take the derivatives of $\int_C{e^{\sqrt{x}t}f(t)dt}$ w.r.t. to $x$ and plug them into the ODE, a factor in $x^{-1/2}$ shows up, and you can't match it with the $x$ factor in the original ODE. But thanks for the answer!